# Removing string from list and returning max value

Tags: python, awk

```
import subprocess
awk1 = subprocess.check_output("awk '{print $1}' "+file+"").decode("utf-8")
print(awk1)
```

This code gives me the result I'm looking for; I'm using `AWK` because I've found it easier extracting $2 - $5 rather than using `Python`.

When I print awk1 it gives me;

```
HEADER
DESCRIPTION (can be over multiple lines)
TEST TYPE 
RESULTS (numbers below are just examples)
-999.00
-500
-100.15
+1
+23.111
+500
```

What I'd like to do is determine if any of the results are greater than -500. I tried to use `max()` but this is throwing out errors because I have str and `int`s present. Also for some reason, if I try to put this in a loop (`for i in akw1` ....) it'll print it vertically, such as;

```
1
0
0
.
1
5

Instead of 100.15
```

The lines at the beginning on the result can be of varied length, and also lines within the result could contain strings. Which would be the most efficient way to remove the strings and then determine if the number is greater than the specified amount? Thank you.

Comment: why you don't try initiating a blank string , and then you add the result (by the end of each instance of the loop) to the already existing string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) will return `bytes` (which is `str`-like). Thus iterating over it would give you each individual characters e.g. `"H"`, then `"E"`, then `"A"`, etc.

What you can do is split it first by newlines `"\n"`. Then iterate on the list and try to convert to int. If it can be converted, check if it is beyond -500. Else if it can't be converted, then just ignore it and move to the next one.

```
from contextlib import suppress

awk1 = b"""HEADER
DESCRIPTION (can be over multiple lines)
TEST TYPE 
RESULTS (numbers below are just examples)
-999.00
-500
-100.15
+1
+23.111
+500"""

for text in awk1.decode().split(b'\n'):
    with suppress(Exception):
        if float(text) > -500:
            print("Found", text)
            break
else:
    print("Not found")
```

**Output**

```
Found b'-100.15'
```

Comment: That was great, thank you very much for you help. I added in a quick array to collect any/all values that meet the criteria and then pulled the biggest value from the array.

array1 = []

for text in awk1.decode().split('\n'):
    with suppress(Exception):
        if float(text) < -500:
            array1.append(text)

print(array1)
print(max(array1))

Comment: Glad it helped :) If it's all the answer you need, you might want to accept it as the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers